# ECMAScript2015 class vs Object.create vs new vs Object.setPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

With the appearance of ES6 we got a new way of creating objects. My question is how should we create objects now?
Let's say that the new operator works like this

```
function createNewObject(parentFunction){
    var obj = {};
    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, parentFunction.prototype);
    return parentFunction.apply(obj, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)) || obj;
}
```

But what exactly is happening when class is created? And what is the current "proper" way of creating objects in es6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With es6 we would create a class using the following syntax:

```
class Animal{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    } 
    saySomething(){
        console.log('Hi, my name is' + this.name);
    }
}
```

If we want to create a sub class called `Cat`, it would look like this:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor(name){
        super(name);
    }   
    saySomething(){
        console.log('Meow, my name is ' + this.name);
    }
}
```

If we want to create an object of type `Cat`, we would do this:

```
let cat1 = new Cat('Felix');
cat1.saySomething(); //Outputs 'meow, my name is Felix'
```

The es6 class feature is syntactic sugar over the prototype method. If we were to create the `Animal` class using a regular prototype method it would look like this:

```
var Animal = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.saySomething = function(){
   console.log('hi, my name is ' + this.name);
}
```

And the subclass would look like this:

```
var Cat = function(name){
    Animal.call(this, name);
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.saySomething = function(){
  console.log('Meow, my name is ' + this.name);
}
```

Comment: the question also talks about difference between Object.create and Object.setPrototypeOf. But answer does not even mention Object.setPrototypeOf. Cant understand how the answer got selected.

Comment: Quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf:"The Object.setPrototypeOf() method sets the prototype (i.e., the internal [[Prototype]] property) of a specified object to another object or null."